# Loop until using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I write a loop with an until condition using Java 8 streams?

```
void readValue(char[] buf, int len, int curIndex) {
        for(; curIndex < len; curIndex++) {
            if(buf[curIndex] == '|') {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print(buf[curIndex]);
            }
        }
}
```

When I use filter, it filters all the '|' characters. I want to break out when I encounter the first one.

```
    Arrays.stream(buf, curIndex, len)
          .filter(n -> n != '|')
          .forEach(k -> System.out.print(k));
```

Comment: In short, from the duplicate: not easily; it's probably easier just to do it the old-fashioned way.  Also, recall that there is no `CharStream`; the chars will get promoted to ints, which will not be `System.out.print`ed the same way.

Comment: If you just need to print them, something like `System.out.println(new String(buf, curIndex, IntStream.range(curIndex, len).filter(i -> buf[i] == '|').findFirst().orElse(len)));` might work.